# nasm - assembly language introduction

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to learn assembly language in my spare time to help me in my role as a developer using high level languages.

I have followed the NASM tutorial here: http://leto.net/writing/nasm.php.

I am able to create and run a simple program that prints HelloWorld to the screen.  I am confused by the following paragraph in the link above:

```
mov eax,5       ; the syscall number for open()

So where do find out all of the semantics for all of the various system calls?
Well first, the numbers are listed in asm/unistd.h in Linux, and  sys/syscall.h
in the *BSD's
```

I assume that this means that: if there is a 5 in the eax register, then it is a system call for open.  Are the rest of the system calls documented somewhere?

I am using NASM on a Windows 7 PC.

Comment: bsd/linux syscall IDs aren't going to be of much use if you're running under Windows...

Comment: @Marc B, thanks.  Do you know what the equivalent of syscalls are in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List of Windows API calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If and when you use NASM on Linux,

http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html#1

http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/

Comment: Thanks.  I have used the Windows API with C++, but not with assembly.  Is it fair to say that the Windows API is equivalent to SYSCALL in Linux?

Comment: `int 80` in *nix, are equivalent to DOS interrupts.  Modern versions of windows DO use syscall/sysenter, and interrupts, but user mode apps cannot use them.  We use the Windows API to interact with the OS.

Comment: Finally, I take it that user mode apps can use syscalls in Linux? (I don't have ang programming experience with Linux).

Comment: Yes, the old way of doing things in Linux was to use interrupts (You can still use them).  The newer way to get things done, is to use `syscall`.  The ABI is different between 32bit OS and 64bit OS's

Comment: Do you know of a link of windows syscalls with register values (similar to the third link in your answer, but for windows). Last  question I promise.

Comment: No.. you have to use the Windows API, especially on Win7 and newer.

Comment: In your first comment you said that none user mode applications use them. It would be helpful if I could see them.

Comment: If you have to ask, then it is too advanced for you to write drivers or RING0 apps in Assembly.